# Notification message on method declaration when working in Netbeans

Tags: php, algorithm, optimization, netbeans

I have a FOREACH statement nested in an IF statement.

for some reason netbeans 7.4 thinks this is bad coding...: "Too many nested blocks in function declaration"

But i can't create a function just for looping through the object...is that good coding behavior or just netbeans issue?

I want to make sure i'm writing proper code since this is part of a larger project.

### EDIT:

```
$client = $aws->get('ElasticTranscoder');

try {
    $result = $client->ListPipelines(array());
    if (!empty($result['data']['Pipelines'])) {
        foreach ($result['data']['Pipelines'] as $pipeline) {
            echo $pipeline->PipelineId;
        }
    }

    //print_r($result);
} catch (ElasticTranscoderException $e) {

}
```

Comment: There is no general answer to that question. You will have to show the code.

Comment: added code per request... :)

Comment: You might want to check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256770/why-is-it-a-good-idea-to-avoid-nested-blocks-in-a-function-php

Comment: @PatrickKostjens, yeap read it....still doesnt explain it...or i just didn't understand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to a similar question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256770/why-is-it-a-good-idea-to-avoid-nested-blocks-in-a-function-php). I will add a little more explanation though, as requested.

In the question I referred to, the complexity of a function depends on the number of decision points in the function. A lot of decision points (`if`, `for`, etc.) indicate a more complex function. Complex functions are more difficult to test since there are a lot of possible flows. In your case however, the `if` and the `for` both use the same variable and an `if` block to check the contents of a variable with a `for`-loop in it that iterates over the variable, is not a bad practice in my opinion. It simply prevents warnings and therefore it is therefore not a problem. This could be different though, if the `for` and the `if` were relatively unrelated.

Comment: that's what i thought... :)